# Python Translator

Tags: python

Trying to create client server side application where the server takes input message and translate it.

```
import socket
portNum=6000
serverSocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind((socket.gethostname(),portNum))
print("The server is ready to be used")


def translator(message):
    starting = message[0]

    if starting == ("a" or "e" or "i" or "u"):
        newMessage = message + start + ay
        return newMessage
    else:
        message = message[1:] + starting + "ay"
        return message


while True:
    message,clientAddress=serverSocket.recvfrom(4096)
    newMessage= message.decode()
    translator(message)
    serverSocket.sendto(newMessage.encode(),clientAddress)
```

Comment: What  error you are getting ?

Answer (score 2):

You never assign the output of translator to a variable. Try changing the line

```
translator(message)
```

to

```
newMessage = translator(newMessage)
```